# Two related limit questions - Measure theory

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification, lebesgue-integral

Let $(X, \mu)$ be a measure space and $f:(X, A) \rightarrow (\mathbb{R}, B(\mathbb{R}))$ a non-negative function with $\int_{X}f d\mu < \infty$ I want to show

1: $\lim_{i \to \infty}\int_{\{x \in X: f(x) >i\}}f d\mu = 0$

2: $\lim_{i \to \infty}i \mu (\{x \in X: f(x) >i\})=0$

Attempt:

For 1: I want to use DCT but am not sure what function I can take as my sequence.

Let $f_{i}$ be a sequence converging to $0$ pointwise and be lebesgue integrable. Initially I choose $f_{i}=\frac{1}{i}$ but I think that fails on the integrability criteria? Then let the dominating function be $f_{1}$. Then there exists an integrable function $f$ such that $f = \lim_{i \to \infty}f_{i}$ and we would then have $\lim_{i \to \infty}\int_{\{x \in X:f(x)>i\}}f_{i} d \mu = \int_{\{x \in X: f(x)>i\}}\lim_{i \to \infty}f_{i} d\mu = \int_{\{x \in X:f(x)>i\}}f d\mu = 0$

I do know since $f$ is non-negative I can find a monotonic sequence that converges to $f$.

2: This looks like I can maybe apply Chebyshev Inequality:

$\mu(\{x \in X: f(x)>i\}) < \frac{1}{i}\int_{\{x \in X: f(x) >i\}}f d\mu$ Which by part 1 I know this limit converges to $0$ so the result follows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $|\chi_{\{f>i\}}f| \le |f|$ and that pointwise $\chi_{\{f>i\}}f \to 0, i \to\infty$. Since since $f \in L^1$, DCT implies:
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{i \to \infty}\int_{\{f>i\}}f \mathrm{d}\mu = \lim_{i \to \infty}\int_{X}\chi_{\{f>i\}}f \mathrm{d}\mu =0 \;.
\end{equation*}
It follows that
\begin{equation*}
i\mu[f>i] = \int_{\{f>i\}} i\mathrm{d}\mu \le\int_{\{f>i\}} f\mathrm{d}\mu \to 0, \qquad i \to\infty\;.
\end{equation*}

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. Does my part 1 look okay, or does it need amending. If it needs amending it looks like I can use a similar argument and just take $f_{i} = \chi_{f >i}f_{i}$?

Comment: after looking at your post again, I'm a bit confused. What have you taken as your sequence of functions $f_{i}$?

Comment: Does the answer to this question solve your doubt? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3412510/using-dominated-convergence-theorem-with-continuous-limits